# Convert a code signing certificate from Sectigo/Comodo into a .pfx file that is actually usable

Tags: openssl, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, codesignkey

When I tried to download the code signing certificate from Sectigo/Comodo, using Firefox I just ended up downloading a file called `CollectCCC`, with no file extension. It is not clear to me how to use it to sign a binary. When I try to use it to sign a binary (with `/debug` on) I get the following:

```
> .\installation\signtool.exe sign /debug /f 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\CollectCCC' .\DraughtHub_Link.exe

The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: GoDragons
    Issued by: Sectigo RSA Code Signing CA
    Expires:   Fri Oct 22 00:59:59 2021
    SHA1 hash: <hash>

    Issued to: Sectigo RSA Code Signing CA
    Issued by: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
    Expires:   Wed Jan 01 00:59:59 2031
    SHA1 hash: <hash>

    Issued to: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
    Issued by: AAA Certificate Services
    Expires:   Mon Jan 01 00:59:59 2029
    SHA1 hash: <hash>

    Issued to: AAA Certificate Services
    Issued by: AAA Certificate Services
    Expires:   Mon Jan 01 00:59:59 2029
    SHA1 hash: <hash>

After EKU filter, 4 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 4 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Part of the problem is that I wasn't able to download their certificate using IE (their recommended way, sigh), because I hadn't created a code signing certificate request using IE. I created the code signing certificate request using `openssl`.

Here is the error message I got from IE:
[image: IE error message]

I tried importing the `CollectCCC` into IE as well and that failed.

Disclaimer: I would not recommend using Sectigo and/or Comodo for code signing certificates! My experience with them was terrible! It's worth paying more to get a better service.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

After a lot of googling, I eventually worked out that the `CollectCCC` file is of type `.p7s`.

You can convert `.p7s` files into `.pfx` files (required to sign binaries) using `openssl` with the following commands (it's a two step process):

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in CollectCCC -print_certs -out CollectCCC.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey ~/.csr/www.draughthub.com.key -in CollectCCC.pem
```

where you replace `~/.csr/www.draughthub.com.key` with the location of the private key you created to make the code sign certificate request. The second step will prompt you for a password. This is the password you used to create the request (and corresponding private key).

Comment: Thank god I've found this. I literally tries all the openssl commands in any combination.

Comment: Sectigo/Comodo is the worst garbage service I've ever used. Thanks for providing this when they won't even say what the damn file format is.

Comment: Thank you for this post! Agreed with @NateS, Sectigo/Comodo is *astonishingly* bad. After all the fuss about verifying my company (which took *3 months*) they give me a random binary file with no instructions, no extension, no information about its format. What a joke.

Unfortunately most folks (like me) won't know this until they end up on a StackOverflow page like this. Best of luck to anyone else unfortunate enough to be their customer.

Comment: Thank you! Goes to show that there must be a reason for Sertigo not properly investing in their email cert business. Probably easy money for a relatively unknown business.

Then again, not opting for the first cheap option would be a good thing anyway when it comes to security. If they use this kind of experience when acquiring such a certificate, what would their internal security policy/practice even be.

Answer (score 6):

I went through this process recently and I also had troubles with this process. After I bought a code signing certificate from Sectigo, I had to:

**Step 1.** Create a certificate request file (.csr) and the certificate key file (.key). After this you will have 2 files, one with **.key** extension and one with **.csr** extension.

**openssl.exe req -nodes -newkey rsa:3072 -nodes -keyout DESIREDNAME.key -out DESRIREDNAME.csr -subj "/C=COUNTRY_CODE/ST=STATE_NAME/L=CITY_NAME/O=ORGANIZATION_NAME /CN=YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com"**

**Step 2.** Use the **.csr** file on Sectigo website to generate your certificate.

**Step 3.** Download your certificate from the email received from Sectigo. After this step you should have a new file with **.crt** extension, in my case it was **user.crt**.

**Step 4.** Convert the **.key** and **.crt** files to a **.pfx** file for code signing.

**openssl.exe pkcs12 -inkey DESIREDNAME.key -in user.crt -export -out mycertificate.pfx**

During this process you will be asked to set a password for the **.pfx** file.

**Step 5.** Dual sign the file with SHA1 and SHA256.

**signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha1 /fd sha1 /f mycertificate.pfx /p MY_CERT_PASSWORD myapp.exe**

**signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /as /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f mycertificate.pfx /p MY_CERT_PASSWORD myapp.exe**

Note that the second call contains the **/as** parameter to append the signature. Remember, always sign with SHA1 first and append the SHA256 second.

**Step 6.** Right click your file and select Properties. Check the Digital Signatures tab. Your file should be now digitally signed. Congratulations!

**Some side notes:**

At **Step 1** I have used one **openssl.exe** found in **C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe** but this one failed at **Step 4** with "can't find certificates" error. I had to install **Win64 OpenSSL Light** from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and then **Step 4** worked as expected and my **.pfx** file was finally generated.

I did not have **signtool.exe** available on my machine, so from **Visual Studio Installer** I selected to modify the installation and I added one of the **Windows 10 SDK** item from **Individual Components**. Then I had this file available in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10xxxx\x64\signtool.exe**.

Can't wait to see those AV false positives go away now that my application is digitally signed :)

Comment: Well, not that easy because I could not afford an EV code signing certificate :( But it is still better than no signature at all.

Answer (score 1):

I did had this issue... I had to renew a 'code certificate' and at every steps, I had difficulties with Sectigo... (Really this s...)  Finally, at the 'last' step, I followed their instructions to 'download' the certificate and I found myselfe with a 'CollectCCC' file and no more explanations (real champs those Sectigo guys!).  Did reach (again) tech support and they asked me to reach my intermediate company which I purchased the certificate from in order to finalise.  Talked with the tech guy and the tips was to do the exact opposite from what they say in their emails (the ask to use Internet Explorer (forget it) or Firefox to download the file.... BUT if you actuelly use 'Chrome' the file you download is not the 'CollectCCC' thing BUT an actual valid .crt file!!!  I did test that with tech support from my provider and if you do the opposite from what they say (use Chrom) IT DOES WORK!!!  Wow!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).